# What is the murderer's motive for killing Oliver Whyte?

Tags: plot-explanation, mystery-of-a-hansom-cab

In *The Mystery of a Hansom Cab*, what was

> Roger Moreland's

motive for killing Oliver Whyte?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to why you're trying to establish what the motive is?

Comment: Also, if the name in the question's title could be considered a spoiler, please change it.

Comment: @MattD It's not. It's a murder mystery... so him dying is what sets off the entire story.

Comment: @Catija Gotcha. I'm unfamiliar with the movie myself but just wanted to bring it to OP's attention in the event it was a spoiler, given our rules about them being in titles here.

Comment: " Could you be more specific as to why you're trying to establish what the motive is?" Because when the murderer's identity was revealed, I couldn't follow why he did it. "Also, if the name in the question's title could be considered a spoiler, please change it." The murder happens about five minutes into the show, and the victim's name was on the back of the DVD box, so I don't think that's a spoiler.

Comment: There is really no need to put the content in spoiler markup. It's a very minor TV movie from Australia... I don't think anyone will care.